# How to query objects within 1000m epsg4326?

Tags: postgis

I have a PostGIS table having a column "geom" having a type `geometry(MultiPolygon)` and the projection epsg:4326 (degree decimal), I want to query all objects within 1000m and I use this query:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM table 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, 'POINT(long lat)', 1000.0);
```

but I always ended up querying all objects.

Comment: Do you want to know the objects that are in the 1000m radius of your point?

Comment: no, thats why i am querying it. :(

Comment: but i know that my table having 200000 rows is scattered more than 500km

Answer (score 4):

Cast your geometries to GEOGRAPHY type:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM table WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(long lat)'), 1000.0);
```

otherwise, PostGIS will treat the value "1000" as 1000 decimal degrees, which effectively means "return all objects".

Answer (score 0):

For a multipolygon column, this works for me:

```
SELECT
    ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) 
FROM table 
   WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(geom, 1000), 'SRID=4326;POINT(long lat)'::geometry);
```

**EDIT**

Michal is right with the buffer. I tried it without using the geography type and this seems to work as well.

```
SELECT
    ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)
FROM table 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, 'SRID=4326;POINT(long lat)'::geometry, 1000);
```

Comment: but my point is also in degree decimal :(

Comment: I changed my query to a more common one. For lat and long insert your data in degree decimal. I tried it with data in my database and they were in gauss krueger coordinates (german stuff).

Comment: -1. ST_Buffer adds too much overhead, this function should be used only if you intend to visualize the search radius.

Comment: You're right. Having a lot of data this is a slow workaround. Whatever, I will leave my first answer here. Is it really necessary to cast to the geography type? I think the query I've additionally added to my post does the job as well.